# How do I get the releated object names?

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem that I've been trying to resolve for hours. Let's say that I have a book model, an author model and a country model.

When viewing a book entry, at the bottom of the page, there are the related objects. In this case, authors.

The page shows me the related data for the author, the author's name and other details display fine. The country, however, is displayed as country_id.

Is there a way that I can change that to country name?

UPDATE:

I have these three tables:
Book HMBM Authors H Country

A book may be written by many authors (for anthologies)

An author may write many books

An author may reside in a country

A country may host may authors.

Book:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Author' => array(
        'className' => 'Author',
        'joinTable' => 'author_books',
        'foreignKey' => 'book_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'author_id',
        'unique' => '',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Author:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Book' => array(
        'className' => 'Book',
        'foreignKey' => 'book_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Country' => array(
        'className' => 'Country',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
```

Country:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Author' => array(
        'className' => 'Author',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
```

Comment: without actual code here (what you do to retrieve the data) no one will actually be able to help you properly.

Comment: you also need to post your model relations you set up (in the models)

Comment: I'll post it later. The reason I didn't post any more information than I did because all of my questions that had more information did not receive a reply -_- Thank you for your interest. I'll add it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If a book has an author, and an author has a country, the data you require is outside the ORM's mechanism to avoid recursive calls to the database. Call `$this->Book->recursive = 2`in your controller method to increase the recursion limit.

Comment: -2 should be 2 - but I still highly advice against this in favor of the better approach using containable.

Comment: Setting the recursive doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately, elliot. 

Don't worry, you can submit an answer too mark :)

Comment: You're right, it should be 2 - fixed! Recursive will work but will slow down the response. Forgot about Containable, that's a much better approach.

Comment: Make sure it's set before you make any find() or read() calls. As noted by @mark, you're much better off using Containable

Comment: $this->Book->id = $id;
        $this->Book->recursive = 2;

        if (!$this->Book->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid book'));
        }
        $this->set('book', $this->Book->read(null, $id));

Well I **think** I'm doing it right.

Comment: Look, guys. I need some help with this. Recursive doesn't work and contain isn't either. Can you _please_ help me on this?

Comment: Just a question. Can I actually get the name of the country in the author part of the view book page, or am I just pushing against the wall?